# The mapping degree of a map generated by quadratic polynomials

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, polynomials, differential-topology

Consider a proper map $F: \mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{R}^{2n-1}(n\geq 2)$ such that each component of $F$ is given by a sesquilinear form on $\mathbb{C}^n$. This to say, each component of $F$ can be written explicitly as

$\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n} a_{ij}z_i\bar{z_j}$

for some $a_{ij}=\bar{a_{ji}}\in\mathbb{C}$.

Since $F$ is homogeneous of degree 2 and $S^1$ invariant, $F$ is proper implies it induces a continuous map,

$\tilde{F}: \mathbb{CP}^{n-1}\to \mathbb{S}^{2n-2}$.

My question is whether the mapping degree of $\tilde{F}$ can only be $0,\pm 1$ (This is true for n=2). There are examples showing these numbers are realizable. For deg=1, one can take:

$F_1=|z_1|^2-\sum_{2\leq i\leq n} |z_i|^2$

$F_{2k-2}=2\text{Re}(z_1\bar{z_k})$

$F_{2k-1}=2\text{Im}(z_1\bar{z_k})$, $2\leq k\leq n$.

In particular, is degree 2 realizable for some $n\geq 3$? Does anyone have a quick example?

Comment: If one is willing to use $S^1$ invariant homogeneous polynomials of degree 4 on $\mathbb{C}^n$, then as along as we are willing also to increase the dimension $n$, large degrees can be achieved. For instance, we can try $\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^n, (z_1,\cdots,z_n)\to (z_1^2,\cdots, z_n^2)$ and then compose this map with the quadratic map above. So it is only reasonable to ask this question for quadratic polynomials